# Pushing secret keys to heroku, safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I have an app with several secret keys stored in various yml files e.g. amazon aws keys stored in amazon.yml, pusher keys stored in pusher.yml and plenty more for various other features.

The codebase for the app is stored in a private (paid) GitHub repository, so the keys are protected from public access. However, I'm planning on pushing to heroku - and I will be pushing the application as is.

Will the keys be accessible to the public this way? Or does heroku do a good job of hiding/protecting the GitRepo that is pushed to heroku's server.

Please help clear this up for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both the repo and app config settings are accessible only to people who have been authorized to access the app.

Comment: Thanks @mipadi! So it's safe to push the source code up to heroku then? Cheers

Comment: Subject to the usual caveats, like Heroku could get hacked or something, same with any other web service.

Answer (score 0):

Further to `@mipadi`, [Heroku's system runs on AWS](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security) - which basically means it manages a VPS / server instance on your behalf

--

**ENV**

The ENV variables in your Heroku app are best likened to the [Unix ENV variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), often stored in `/etc/environment` on a VPS. These are OS-level variables, which means that only if someone gains access to the OS can the variables be accessed / used

--

**Code**

When you mention the safety of deploying the source to Heroku, you need to remember that Heroku also uses the [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) SCM system - meaning you're pushing the git-ready version of your code. All the dependencies, sensitive data & database storage is not linked to your Heroku app directly; giving you extra security

---

If you're truly concerned with Heroku's security, your best bet is to get a VPS on the likes of [RackSpace](http://rackspace.com) or similar. However, it's the same setup whether you use Heroku or not